# How do I determine the weight to assign to each bucket?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, linear-programming

Someone will answer a series of questions and will mark each important (I), very important (V), or extremely important (E). I'll then match their answers with answers given by everyone else, compute the percent of the answers in each bucket that are the same, then combine the percentages to get a final score.

For example, I answer 10 questions, marking 3 as extremely important, 5 as very important, and 2 as important. I then match my answers with someone else's, and they answer the same to 2/3 extremely important questions, 4/5 very important questions, and 2/2 important questions. This results in percentages of 66.66 (extremely important), 80.00 (very important), and 100.00 (important). I then combine these 3 percentages to get a final score, but I first weigh each percentage to reflect the importance of each bucket. So the result would be something like: $score = E * 66.66 + V * 80.00 + I * 100.00$. The values of E, V, and I (the weights) are what I'm trying to figure out how to calculate.

The following are the constraints present:

$1 + X + X^2 = X^3$

$E >= X * V >= X^2 * I > 0$

$E + V + I = 1$

$E + 0.9 * V >= 0.9$

$0.9 > 0.9 * E + 0.75 * V >= 0.75$

$E + I < 0.75$

When combining the percentages, I could give important a weight of 0.0749, very important a weight of .2501, and extremely important a weight of 0.675, but this seems arbitrary, so I'm wondering how to go about calculating the optimal value for each weight. Also, how do I calculate the optimal weights if I ignore all constraints?

As far as what I mean by optimal: while adhering to the last 4 constraints, I want the weight of each bucket to be the maximum possible value, while having the weights be as far apart as possible (extremely important questions weighted maximally more than very important questions, and very important questions weighted maximally more than important questions).

Comment: What is $X$? When you say "optimal", what are you trying to optimise?

Comment: Are the constraints for each question? Are the questions independent? $I$, $V$, and $E$ are what? The percentage of the answers for one question? An array of percentages for all answers?

Comment: @DrXorile, the first equation is solvable, and results in X equaling approximately 1.83. While adhering to the last 4 constraints, I want the weight of each bucket to be the maximum possible value, while having the weights be as far apart as possible(extremely important questions weighted maximally more than very important questions, and very important questions weighted maximally more than important questions). Also, the constraints are on the weights, a question can only be given one weight, and I, V, and E are the weights I'm trying to calculate.

Comment: So this would appear to lend itself well to a graphical interpretation. If you plot E on the y-axis and the V on the x-axis, then the various inequalities can be plotted to give you a region. The I value can also be plotted as contours of slope -1. This will show you all the possible results for I, V, and E. I suspect you'll need something more to constrain it, but possibly you'll just pick the biggest value of I that fits the other constraints

Answer (score 0):

Assigning weights is one way to go, and you can do this without constraints, but if you want an overall score for each question, but ideally you would probably also like to rank the questions in some non-trivial way. And the ranking will depend on the weights, and like you said you don't know what the "optimal" weights are. For this, you can compute how many of each response you got for each question, and then sample repeatedly uniformly (i.e. from the sphere) triples of weights that are in the proper order, and rank the questions accordingly. Then whichever ranking of questions you get the most with your weight samples is the one you can define to be the "best", and any triplet of weights that give you that ordering (or the average of all triplets that give you that ordering) can be deemed to be the "best" weights.

If you want to include weight constraints, it looks like your equality constraint on $X$ restricts it to be at most 3 possibilities, and the rest are equations/inequalities that can be satisfied as long as you respect the inequalities and ensure that weights $(c_I,c_V,c_E)$ satisfy $c_I + c_V + c_E = 1$. You can sample weights $(c_I,c_V,c_E)$ from the sphere in the proper order and then normalize so that the sum is 1, and then keep the weights if they satisfy your inequalities, otherwise discard. Then the same methodology above for choosing the "best" weights and the "best" ordering of questions still applies. This is all, assuming of course, that you like the framework. In truth, if you are going to use weights, then the "best" weights could be anything satisfying your constraints, unless you are willing to make further assumptions, such as what I have laid out here.